# Add dynamically radio button to JSP Form

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, radio-button

I was trying to add dynamically extra fields to a Form. However only text/number fields are getting created as expected. The radio buttons got created but the choose list is being shared with all the objects. Also notice Im closing the FORM after the script close otherwise path FORM input will throw and error. rAny idea what Im missing? Thank you in advance.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-5 p-1">
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="investmentForm" class="p-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="inputFormRow">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><h5><b>Invoice ID</b></h5></label>
                        <form:input path="invoiceNumber" name="invoiceNumber[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="E001-1234" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><h5><b>Amount</b></h5></label>
                        <form:input path="amountForm" name="amount[]" type="number" class="form-control m-input"  step=".01" required="required" min="1" max="10000"/>
                    </div>
                    <label><h5><b>Currency</b></h5></label>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <form:radiobuttons class="form-check-input" path="currency" items="${curr}"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="newRow"></div>
                <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add Row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn mt-4 btn-block p-2 btn-success shadowed">Invest!</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // add row
    var counter = 1;
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        counter += 1;
        var html ='<div id="inputFormRow">'
            +'<div class="form-group">'
            +'<label><h5><b>Invoice ID</b></h5></label>'
            +'<form:input path="invoiceNumber" name="invoiceNumber[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="E001-1234" required="required" />'
            +'</div>'
            +'<div class="form-group">'
            +'<label><h5><b>Amount</b></h5></label>'
            +'<form:input path="amountForm" name="amount[]" type="number" class="form-control m-input"  step=".01" required="required" min="1" max="10000"/>'
            +'</div>'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            +'<label><h5><b>Currency</b></h5></label>'
            +'<div class="form-check form-check-inline">'
            +'<label class="form-check-label">'
            +'<form:radiobuttons class="form-check-input" path="currency" items="${curr}"/>'
            +'</label>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<div class="input-group-append">'
            +'<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>'
            +'</div>'
            +'</div>'

        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });

    // remove row
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });
</script>
</form:form>
```

[image: Current Behavior]

Comment: This is happening because name of radio button is same when you append new row i,.e: `currency` you need to give different name to radio button . So that it differs from other radio button .